# SVM Params : On what basis the different parameters should be set in opencv (3D data)?

Tags: c++, opencv, 3d, classification, svm

I have been working on Classifications of 3D Objects using SVM Classifier,
I'm stuck up at classification step.
I have taken a 3D data : Point Cloud Data, 
For training model to be build, i have applied SIFT 3D detection method to identify the keypoints and FPFH descriptor to extract the features of these keypoints.
Then used K-means clustering algorithm to construct bag of features, I'm giving bag of features along with the label set as an input.

```
SVM.train(trainingDataMat, labelsMat, Mat(), Mat(), params);
```

[CvSVMParams](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html)

I have tried using different combination but failed to get correct output ( accuracy), like out of 5 classes, i can predict at the most 3 classes correctly.
Please help me.

Comment: can you tell what is your params ?

Comment: CvSVMParams params;
    params.svm_type    = CvSVM::C_SVC;
 params.kernel_type = CvSVM::RBF;
 params.gamma=10;
 params.coef0=10;
  params.term_crit   = cvTermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_ITER+CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 1000, FLT_EPSILON );
 params.C=10;

This is what i have taken as parameters.

Comment: It could be possible that your training data for different classes are very close to each other. So you can try following things, 1. Try choosing higher value of c, which aims at classifying all training examples correctly. 2. Try mapping features to higher dimension using polynomial kernel. 3. Do a grid search of (C,gamma) and find out the optimal value. 4. Try using nu_SVM. You have to try different combination which suits your data. Hope this helps